# Mapbox Reverse Geocoding

Tags: null, response, geocoding, reverse, mapbox

I have looked at the links but cannot find a simple example of reverse geocoding using the Mapbox API.

Does anybody have a link to a simple partial address input and a response?

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't the example's in: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#reverse-geocoding work for you ?

At least when trying those quickly with browser, they return nice JSON reply. So for Reply, just copy paste the url into your browser, and let it load the response.

Comment: I want to incorporate a box for text on a map and get the coordinates so I am looking for an example that shows how to call the reverse geocoder and the response function.  Also I am not sure of the structure of the returned info.

Comment: Basically the URL is an example, you would use normal HTTP GET with it, and then the reply for the query would be the response you are looking for. I can not see any definition on the site for the JSON format, thus you might need to check what's in the result part of that returned JSON.

Comment: Also if you want more API like functionality, then I suppose you could look into different offerings. For Example Google has their own as well as does the HERE have.

Comment: No need to thank, there is always the ways used here in Stack overflow to indicate whether you found the answer acceptable and/or usefull

Answer (score 3):

Reference

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/geocoding/

Examples

Place to Co-ordinates

example query for the address “515 15th St NW, Washington, DC 20004”,

https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/515%2015th%20St%20NW%2C%20Washington%2C%20DC%2020004.json?types=address&access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN

Co-ordinates to Place

https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/-122.463%2C%2037.7648.json?access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend, point is a type you can construct easily with
Point.fromLngLat(point.longitude(), point.latitude())

```
   private fun reverseGeocode(point: Point) {
    try {
        val client = MapboxGeocoding.builder()
            .accessToken(getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
            .query(Point.fromLngLat(point.longitude(), point.latitude()))
            .geocodingTypes(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_ADDRESS)
            .build()

        client.enqueueCall(object : Callback<GeocodingResponse>
        {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<GeocodingResponse>, response: Response<GeocodingResponse>) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    val results = response.body()!!.features()
                    if (results.size > 0) {
                        val feature = results.get(0)
                        Log.d(TAG, "lig Current location is ${feature.placeName()}")
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "lig Current location is nothing")
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<GeocodingResponse>, throwable: Throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Geocoding Failure", throwable)
            }
        })
    } catch (servicesException: ServicesException) {
        Log.e(TAG, servicesException.toString())
        servicesException.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```